# Tensor notation

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, tensor-calculus

I'm trying to understand the Maxwell Stress tensor notation.

I'm given that each element in the tensor is given by

$$T_{ij}=\epsilon_{0}(E_{i}E_{j}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}E^2)+\frac{1}{\mu_{0}}(B_{i}B_{j}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}B^2)$$

I'm confused as to why the $T_{xx}$ element is given by

$$T_{xx}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0}(E^2_{x}-E^2_{y} -E^2_{z})+\frac{1}{2\mu_{0} }(B^2_{x}-B^2_{y} -B^2_{z})$$

I would think that if you plug in x for both i and j, that in the first term you would have $E^2_{x} - \frac{1}{2}E^2$

Could somebody explain what is going on with this? This is from Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics by the way.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realize there was syntax to make sure the latex came up properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$E^2 = E_x^2 + E_y^2 + E_z^2$$
therefore
$$E_x^2 - \frac{1}{2}E^2 = \frac{1}{2}(E_x^2 - E_y^2 - E_z^2).$$

Comment: Oh... Woops. I don't know how I missed that.